# Is the usage of "quite" here to emphasize or take away from the adjective?

Tags: usage

[link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43115/bidimensional-number-sequence)

> The numbers below have been generated using a (quite) simple algorithm.

Is the usage of "quite" above to show that the algorithm is simpler than if he had only written "simple", or harder than if he had only written that?

Comment: "Quite" here is an adverb; it's an _intensifier_ modifying _simple,_ with the meaning "completely, fully, entirely; to the utmost extent or degree." The algorithm is "completely simple;" it couldn't be simpler.

Comment: The placement of "**quite**" isn't okay to me. Shouldn't it be, "*The numbers below have been generated using quite a simple algorithm*"?

Answer (score 1):

In this context "quite" means "very" -- however in other contexts "quite" might strengthen the following word but not as much as "very".  A lot depends on context and (perceived) emphasis.

"The food was quite good." = "It was good/better than expected."

"The food was quite nice." = "It could have been better, but I'm too polite to say so."

"'Oh yes, I quite enjoyed the food,' she said, rolling her eyes."  = sarcasm.

One of the reasons "quite" can mean different things is that it's not commonly used by all English speakers and feels a little bit formal (and possibly British).  So if you hear it from someone who doesn't usually use it, it probably indicates sarcastic emphasis.

Edit:  By "not commonly used by all English speakers" I mean "not in common use everywhere English is spoken".  In this part of the U.S. it sounds "posh" and/or British.

Comment: Do you have research to support your statement that the word _quite_ is "not commonly used by all English speakers?" For instance, there are ~130,000,000 of them in India, and it's far from uncommon there. It's not quite as uncommon in the U.S. as you think, either, it seems to me.

Comment: I hear it a lot in other (AmE) phrases though, as in "Are we there yet? ... Not quite."  or "There were quite a few left."

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew observes, "quite" is a word that can be used straightforwardly or sarcastically, according to the tone of the speaker. "Oh, thats quite all right" can be said with a variety of inflections and a variety of meanings. It is therefore a difficult word to make unambiguous in writing. The clue for me is the enclosure in brackets. Why would you do that except to signal that something not completely straightforward was intended?

My interpretation is that whoever generated those numbers (possibly the writer herself) described the algorithm as simple, but it is being hinted that the algorithm was actually not so simple. It is only "quite simple".
I feel about 80% confident that I have this correct, but do admit that I could be wrong.

In fact this is a very good question.